# What is the RendererAdapter?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

While I couldn't reproduce the issue, please take a look my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MH3b6DTqondaSYruspPf?p=preview).

I received following error when I try to open the dialog in my local workspace:

```
ERROR TypeError: this._renderer.setProperty is not a function
at NgbRadio.set [as value] (radio.js:133)
at updateProp (core.es5.js:11160)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.es5.js:10852)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js:12382)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12321)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:13180)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.es5.js:13121)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AdEditorComponent.html:48)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:13106)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12288)
```

I tested many smaller cases then found the RendererAdapter encloses valid DebugRenderer2 instance in NgbRadio component.[image]

So, I wrote a hack into the NgbRadio and NgbActiveLabel's constructor to test, then the application works fine:

```
this._renderer = _renderer.constructor.name === 'RendererAdapter'? _renderer.delegate: _renderer;
```

And this structure in the template makes the error:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="conditionalProperty">
  <my-component *ngSwitchCase="'case1'" ...></my-component>
  <my-another-comp *ngSwitchCase="'case2'" ...></my-another-comp>
</div>
```

Let me list two cases the dialog could open in my local:

- Do not inject any pipe dependency (they don't care the pipes are my custom or provided from @angular/common) into the components has ngSwitchCase attribute at the template
- Only one component in the ngSwitch div (but could contains other normal divs have ngSwitchCase)

I tested the latest version of Chrome, Safari, and Firefox and my angular version is 4.2.4.

I couldn't find any useful article about RendererAdapter from Google.
I might use above hack to solve this but don't want to ignore what was the real problem. I would appreciate any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default renderer now is [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2). So when you inject a renderer into a component you should use `Renderer2` token:

```
class MyComponent {
   constructor(renderer: Renderer2)
```

However, earlier  versions of Angular used [Renderer](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer) which is now deprecated and to inject it `Renderer` token was used:

```
class MyComponent {
   constructor(renderer: Renderer)
```

`RendererAdapter` is a class that maps old API to new API, for example, the first renderer had `listenGlobal` method, while the latter API uses `listen`. And here is the mapping for this specific method:

```
  listenGlobal(target: string, name: string, callback: Function): Function {
      return this.delegate.listen(target, name, <any>callback);
  }
```

where delegate is an instance of `Renderer2`.

If you don't use `Renderer` injection token the `RendererAdapter` will not be created. It's possible that the version of `ngbRadio` uses old renderer. The current version [seem to be using new renderer](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/buttons/radio.ts#L153).

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17558
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17378

Comment: It looks weird. I don't use Renderer injection and ng-bootstrap in my local is also the latest version, so Ngb-Components require Renderer2 explicitly. But the DI provides old Renderer. Thanks for your answer. I'll watch these angular's issue.