# Renderer.setAttribute is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-material

i keep on getting the error renderer. setAttribute is not a function when trying to implement material design 2 table component in Angular2

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: renderer.setAttribute is not a function
TypeError: renderer.setAttribute is not a function
at MdTable.CdkTable (cdk.es5.js:1869)
at new MdTable (material.es5.js:20855)
at createClass (core.es5.js:10924)
at createDirectiveInstance (core.es5.js:10742)
at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12178)
at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12624)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12533)
at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12205)
at createRootView (core.es5.js:12073)
at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13456)
at MdTable.CdkTable (cdk.es5.js:1869)
at new MdTable (material.es5.js:20855)
at createClass (core.es5.js:10924)
at createDirectiveInstance (core.es5.js:10742)
at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12178)
at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12624)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12533)
at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12205)
at createRootView (core.es5.js:12073)
at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13456)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:770)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:741)
at zone.js:818
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:191)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:584)
```

Comment: Perhaps some incompatibility. What Angular and components version are you using?

Comment: there was a bug somewhere than Angular kept injecting old renderer where Rendere2 was expected, search the web

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer angular 2 and material design 2 beta 8

Comment: You should update to Angular4

Comment: The material2 package in version 2 beta 8 depends on  "@angular/core": "~4.1.0",

Comment: @Maximus please give more info on that bug

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44793865/2545680

Comment: have same error when using <button md-button></button> inside the md-cell directive. Removing just md-button solves it.